# .net webapi filepath as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering if it is possible somehow to send a relative `filepath` as a string to a GET method.

My method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] string fileName)

My route:
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MiscApiDownload",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/download/{fileName}",
    defaults: new {action = "Download" }
);
```

file names like `"test.jpg"` work but as soon as I have a `subdir` exp. `"folder/test.jpg"` the method cannot be found anymore. Which is logical. Question is if there is a good way to do this in URI. I don't want to receive it in the body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a catchall parameter

```
"api/{controller}/download/{*fileName}"
```

Comment: I think that should be "api/{controller}/download/{*fileName}"

Comment: @JonSusiak Doesn't work for me...What am I missing ?

This is my route config:
 [Route("api/access/{*fileName}")]

This is how I try to invoke it (using browser) :
http://localhost:1354/api/acces/Checkout _ Lenovo US.pdf

It keep tell me "resource not found", any idea ?

(btw i'm using the MapHttpAttributeRoutes)

Comment: Did you try adding / at the end of your url?